# Как протестировать использование сервлетом DB?

Tags: java, servlet, тестирование

Я хочу протестировать что код внутри класса сервлета. А именно правильно ли он использует DB для этого мне нужно использовать динамическую инъекцию зависимостей чтобы подменить реальную DB на mock объект. Однако сделать конструктор с параметрами я не могу, так как он используется tomcat на прямую. Как в таких случаях следует поступать подскажите пожалуйста? Спасибо.

Comment: Разве при тестировании что-то внедряется? Надо как обычно назначить полю db нужное значение. Напрямую или через setter.

Comment: @Sergey создавать setter только для тестирования как то не кошерно, хочется без костылей а по нормальному сделать...

Comment: Сделайте поле public. Или почитайте эту заметку https://blog.jayway.com/2012/02/25/mockito-and-dependency-injection/ Да и вообще пишут, что для тестирования работы с базой данных нужны тесты интеграции а не mock-и. https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-correct-way-to-use-integration-tests-in-your-build-process/